# How to change a module's function

Tags: python-2.7, function, module

I have a module that I want to import. Lets say its name is **module1.py** . 
There is a function inside this module (F(X,Y)). Here is a part of this module:

```
 def F(X,Y):   
   S=complex(X,Y) 
   Fs=2/(pow(S,3))
   Rfs=real(Fs)   
   return Rfs 

Sum=F(X,0)/2.    
print Sum
```

I can import this module by:

```
import module1
```

But I need to change something in the F function after I import it. For example I want to substitute this function in the module with the old one (I want to change Fs in the F function):

```
def F(X,Y):   
   S=complex(X,Y) 
   Fs=1/(S-1)
   Rfs=real(Fs)   
   return Rfs
```

Could you please tell me how I can do that in python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by extending `Module1`. Extending a class allows you to keep all of the previous functions and attributes of the base class but override any that you would like to change.

This example shows that you can call all of the other functions inside of the original `Module1` but that when you call the `F()` function it uses the one from extended class.

### Python2.7

Module1.py

```
class Module1():
    def F(self,X,Y):   
        S=complex(X,Y) 
        Fs=2/(pow(S,3))
        Rfs=real(Fs)   
        return Rfs 

    def G(self):
        return "function G"

    def H(self):
        return "function H"
```

Module1_ext.py

```
import Module1

class Module1(Module1.Module1):
    def F(self,X,Y):
        return X*Y;
```

run.py

```
from Module1_ext import Module1

mod = Module1()
print(mod.G())
print(mod.H())
print(mod.F(2,3))
```

### Python3+

Module1.py

```
class Module1():
    def F(X,Y):   
        S=complex(X,Y) 
        Fs=2/(pow(S,3))
        Rfs=real(Fs)   
        return Rfs 

    def G():
        return "function G"

    def H():
        return "function H"
```

Module1_ext.py

```
import Module1

class Module1(Module1.Module1):
    def F(X,Y):
        return X*Y;
```

run.py

```
from Module1_ext import Module1

print(Module1.G())
print(Module1.H())
print(Module1.F(2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out by myself. This is how I solved the issue:
First we need to rewrite the module in this form:

module1.py

```
from  numpy import *

M = 11
SU = zeros(M + 2)
C = zeros(M + 1)
C[0] = 1
for k in range(1, M + 1):
    C[k] = (M - (k - 1)) * C[k - 1] / k


# T=input("TIME=")
class BB:
  def F(self, fnRf):
    T=1
    A = 19.1
    U = exp(A / 2.) / T
    X = A / (2. * T)
    H = pi / T
    Ntr = 15

    Sum = fnRf(X, 0) / 2.
    for N in range(1, Ntr + 1):
        Y = N * H
        Sum += (-1) ** N * fnRf(X, Y)
    SU[0] = Sum
    for K in range(1, M + 2):
        N = Ntr + K
        Y = N * H
        SU[K] = SU[K - 1] + (-1) ** N * fnRf(X, Y)
    Avgsu = 0.
    Avgsu1 = 0.
    for J in range(M + 1):
        Avgsu += C[J] * SU[J]
        Avgsu1 += C[J] * SU[J + 1]
    Fun = U * Avgsu / 2048
    Fun1 = U * Avgsu1 / 2048
    print Fun1
```

We can import this module like this:

```
from module1 import *

def fnRf(X, Y):
    S = complex(X, Y)
    Fs = 1. / (S-1)
    Rfs = real(Fs)
    return Rfs

ss=BB()
ss.F(fnRf)
```

This way we are flexible to define the function (in the module). Now it works perfectly. I hope it was helpful.